# Add Branch Name to Slack message TFS Service hook

Tags: tfs, slack-api, slack

I am using a service hook to notify my slack channel when ever a build finishes. What I would like to have is the branch name that is being built.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Slack message format is `<Build Format Number><Build Status>` as the screenshot below:

[image]

So you can change the `Build Format Number` in build definition to `$(Build.SourceBranchName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)`. In this way, you can see the branch name in the `Build Format Number`:

[image]